# Salto de línea después de un booleano

Tags: java

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con esto?
Al dar la vuelta como que se salta la línea del usuario y se pasa directamente a la de la contraseña.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner momento = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean seguir = true;
    String usuario, pass;

    while (seguir == true) {
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.print("Usuario: ");
        usuario = momento.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("");
        
        System.out.print("\nContraseña: ");
        pass = momento.nextLine();

        System.out.print("¿Seguir?");
        seguir = momento.nextBoolean();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Coloca tu código escrito y no en imagen para que te podamos ayudar mejor

Comment: @JosueVargas Gracias, ya lo hice.

Answer (score 0):

Yo evaluaría usuario y contraseña de forma individual tipo:

```
//en la clase
public class UserPass {
    //declaramos variables estáticas para que puedan ser utilizadas desde los diferentes métodos de la clase
    static Scanner momento = new Scanner(System.in);
    static boolean seguirU = false, seguirP = false;
    static String usuario, pass, continua = ""; 

    //métoo main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //llama al método que evalúa los datos de uuario y contraseña
        metodoEvaluarDatos();
    
        //si los datos son correctos pregunta si deseamos seguir o repetir el proceso
        if ((seguirU) && (seguirP)){
            System.out.println("desea continuar ? s/n");
            continua = momento.nextLine();
        }
        //ahora evaluamos la respuesta, si es s, sludamos al usuario, si es n, repetimos el proceso llamando de nuevo al método y vaciando las variables
        if (continua.equals("s")){
            System.out.println("Bienvenido " + usuario);
        }
        else{
            usuario = "";
            pass = "";
            metodoEvaluarDatos(); 
        }
    }
    //método que evalúa los datos
    public static void metodoEvaluarDatos(){
        //bule do while que pedirá el usuario mientras no contenga algún carácter
        do {
            System.out.print("");
            //pide el usuario
            System.out.print("Introduzca un Usuario: ");
            //recoge el usuario en la variable usuario
            usuario = momento.nextLine();
        
            //si se introduce algún caracter ponemos la variable booleana a true
            if (!usuario.equals("")){
                seguirU = true;
            }
        /si la variable esta a true, sale del bucle
        }while(!seguirU);
    
        do  {
            //pedimos la contraseña
            System.out.println("Ponga su Contraseña: ");
            //recogemos la contraseña
            pass = momento.nextLine();

            //si se introduce algún carácter
            if (!pass.equals("")){
                //pone la variable booleana a true
                seguirP = true;
            }
        //si está a true, continua el código volviendo al método que lo había llamado
        }while(!seguirP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FAcil el problema es el nextboolean

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner momento = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean seguir = true;
String usuario, pass;

while (seguir == true) {
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.print("Usuario: ");
    usuario = momento.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("");
    
    System.out.print("\nContraseña: ");
    pass = momento.nextLine();

    System.out.print("¿Seguir?");
    seguir = momento.Boolean.parseBoolean(nextLine());
}
```

}